# Automating the Import of Existing Maven Project Into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am creating an installer for a project and would like to import an existing maven project into my eclipse workspace after checking the project out.

I will appreciate any help I can get as soon as possible.

Thanks Guys!

Comment: Please tell us what you did so far. What your problems are. This is no place where someone does the coding for you, we only support.

Answer (score 1):

I automated setting up eclipse, including importing existing maven projects.

First run mvn eclipse:eclipse on the project

```
   mvn eclipse:eclipse:
```

Next grab an eclipse plugin that will perform the headless import of projects into the workspace:

```
   wget https://github.com/snowch/test.myapp/raw/master/test.myapp_1.0.0.jar
```

Copy the above jar to your `/eclipse/dropins/` folder.

Next find all the directories that can be imported into eclipse and append them with '-import'

```
IMPORTS=$(find . -type f -name .project)

# Although it is possible to import multiple directories with one 
# invocation of the test.myapp.App, this fails if one of the imports
# was not successful.  Using a for loop is slower, but more robust
for item in ${IMPORTS[*]}; 
do 
   IMPORT="$(dirname $item)/"
   echo "Importing ${IMPORT}"

   # perform the import using the test.myapp_1.0.0.jar
   eclipse -nosplash \
      -application test.myapp.App \
      -data $WORKSPACE \
      -import $IMPORT
done
```

Finally, add the M2_REPO variable to the workspace

```
mvn eclipse:configure-workspace
```